# Check every URL when it opens Andorid app and compare

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have created an app for Android. I'm facing issues. I want to check every URL which is getting open in that app and if the starts with the given URL then perform task different load URL.

Here is the code I have used:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final WebView web = new WebView(this);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("https://www.facebook.com/connect")) {
                String webUrl = web.getUrl();
                web.loadUrl("http://example.com/test.php?user="+webUrl);
               }
        }
    });

    web.loadUrl("http://example.com");

    setContentView(web);
}
```

Comment: That's your requirement. What is your question?

Comment: I want to check every single url which is getting open in webview how can I  do that ? that's my question

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Actually it is just checking for the 1st load url if url.startwith  but I want to check that condition for every url

Comment: @user3296716 what do you mean by 1st load url? You just called `web.loadUrl()` once, not multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the new url in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`

```
@Override  
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       web.loadUrl(url);  
       return true;  
}
```

Comment: But how can I check every url with that ?